# My Android phone doesn't mount on Lubuntu 15.10

Tags: android

Issue:

I'm using Lubuntu 15.10 Wily i386 and unable to now mount my Android phone via MTP. When I first installed the system, I was able to just plug my phone into USB and access the phone's system files.

Steps Taken to troubleshoot:

```
I've installed the following without any real help:
sudo apt-get install jmtpfs gmtp libmtp libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9 android-tools-adb mtpfs mtp-tools

lubuntu-carecomplex@lubuntucarecomplex-Dimension-3000:~$ go-mtpfs /mnt/mtp
2016/03/12 10:32:07 detect failed: no MTP devices found

lubuntu-carecomplex@lubuntucarecomplex-Dimension-3000:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 034: ID 1bbb:0168 T & A Mobile Phones

lubuntu-carecomplex@lubuntucarecomplex-Dimension-3000:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/mtp
lubuntu-carecomplex@lubuntucarecomplex-Dimension-3000:~$ sudo chmod a+x /mnt/mtp
lubuntu-carecomplex@lubuntucarecomplex-Dimension-3000:~$ mtpfs /mnt/mtp
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=1bbb and PID=0168) is a Alcatel 6030a.
   Found 1 device(s):
   Alcatel: 6030a (1bbb:0168) @ bus 1, dev 34
Attempting to connect device
libusb_get_active_config_descriptor(1) failed: No data available
no active configuration, trying to set configuration
libusb_set_configuration() failed, continuing anyway...: Connection timed out
libusb_get_active_config_descriptor(2) failed: Connection timed out
LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
Unable to open raw device 0

jmtpfs ~/mnt
Device 0 (VID=1bbb and PID=0168) is a Alcatel 6030a.
libusb_get_active_config_descriptor(1) failed: No data available
no active configuration, trying to set configuration
libusb_set_configuration() failed, continuing anyway...: Connection timed out
libusb_get_active_config_descriptor(2) failed: Connection timed out
LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MtpErrorCantOpenDevice'
  what(): Can't open device
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Nothing I do has made this actually able to mount my Android phone. It used to work without a problem. This seems to be a bug.
Can anyone give me some good information. I've allowed the sudo gksudo /etc/fuse.conf the allow non-root users uncommented, gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules = added my vendor/id info as expected, and still nothing.

Here is the best output when I tried MTP-Detect:

```
    libmtp version: 1.1.9

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=1bbb and PID=0168) is a Alcatel 6030a.
   Found 1 device(s):
   Alcatel: 6030a (1bbb:0168) @ bus 1, dev 36
Attempting to connect device(s)
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 2: PTP Layer error 02ff: get_handles_recursively(): could not get object handles.
Error 2: Error 02ff: PTP: I/O error
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
Error 7: Found a bad handle, trying to ignore it.
USB low-level info:
   bcdUSB: 512
   bDeviceClass: 0
   bDeviceSubClass: 0
   bDeviceProtocol: 0
   idVendor: 1bbb
   idProduct: 0168
   IN endpoint maxpacket: 512 bytes
   OUT endpoint maxpacket: 512 bytes
   Raw device info:
      Bus location: 1
      Device number: 36
      Device entry info:
         Vendor: Alcatel
         Vendor id: 0x1bbb
         Product: 6030a
         Vendor id: 0x0168
         Device flags: 0x18008106
Device info:
   Manufacturer: ZX
   Model: MXW1
   Device version: 1.0
   Serial number: W3HKDL11218063
   Vendor extension ID: 0x00000006
   Vendor extension description: microsoft.com: 1.0; android.com: 1.0;
   Detected object size: 64 bits
   Extensions:
        microsoft.com: 1.0
        android.com: 1.0
Supported operations:
   1001: get device info
   1002: Open session
   1003: Close session
   1004: Get storage IDs
   1005: Get storage info
   1006: Get number of objects
   1007: Get object handles
   1008: Get object info
   1009: Get object
   100a: Get thumbnail
   100b: Delete object
   100c: Send object info
   100d: Send object
   1014: Get device property description
   1015: Get device property value
   1016: Set device property value
   1017: Reset device property value
   101b: Get partial object
   9801: Get object properties supported
   9802: Get object property description
   9803: Get object property value
   9804: Set object property value
   9805: Get object property list
   9810: Get object references
   9811: Set object references
   95c1: Get Partial Object (64bit Offset)
   95c2: Send Partial Object
   95c3: Truncate Object
   95c4: Begin Edit Object
   95c5: End Edit Object
Events supported:
   0x4002
   0x4003
   0x4004
   0x4005
Device Properties Supported:
   0xd401: Synchronization Partner
   0xd402: Friendly Device Name
   0x5003: Image Size
Playable File (Object) Types and Object Properties Supported:
   3000: Undefined Type
   3001: Association/Directory
   3004: Text
   3005: HTML
   3008: MS Wave
   3009: MP3
   300b: MPEG
   3801: JPEG
   3802: TIFF EP
   3804: BMP
   3807: GIF
   3808: JFIF
   380b: PNG
   380d: TIFF
   b901: WMA
   b902: OGG
   b903: AAC
   b982: MP4
   b983: MP2
   b984: 3GP
   ba05: Abstract Audio Video Playlist
   ba10: WPL Playlist
   ba11: M3U Playlist
   ba14: PLS Playlist
   ba82: XMLDocument
   b906: FLAC
Storage Devices:
   StorageID: 0x00010001
      StorageType: 0x0003 fixed RAM storage
      FilesystemType: 0x0002 generic hierarchical
      AccessCapability: 0x0000 read/write
      MaxCapacity: 122261504
      FreeSpaceInBytes: 0
      FreeSpaceInObjects: 1073741824
      StorageDescription: Phone Storage
      VolumeIdentifier: (null)
   StorageID: 0x00020001
      StorageType: 0x0004 removable RAM storage
      FilesystemType: 0x0002 generic hierarchical
      AccessCapability: 0x0000 read/write
      MaxCapacity: 1977286656
      FreeSpaceInBytes: 1677721600
      FreeSpaceInObjects: 1073741824
      StorageDescription: SD card
      VolumeIdentifier: (null)
Special directories:
   Default music folder: 0x00000001
   Default playlist folder: 0xffffffff
   Default picture folder: 0xffffffff
   Default video folder: 0xffffffff
   Default organizer folder: 0xffffffff
   Default zencast folder: 0xffffffff
   Default album folder: 0xffffffff
   Default text folder: 0xffffffff
MTP-specific device properties:
   Friendly name: (NULL)
   Synchronization partner: (NULL)
libmtp supported (playable) filetypes:
   Folder
   Text file
   HTML file
   RIFF WAVE file
   ISO MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3
   MPEG video stream
   JPEG file
   BMP bitmap file
   GIF bitmap file
   JFIF file
   Portable Network Graphics
   TIFF bitmap file
   Microsoft Windows Media Audio
   Ogg container format
   Advanced Audio Coding (AAC)/MPEG-2 Part 7/MPEG-4 Part 3
   MPEG-4 Part 14 Container Format (Audio+Video Emphasis)
   ISO MPEG-1 Audio Layer 2
   Abstract Playlist file
   XML file
   Free Lossless Audio Codec (FLAC)
ERROR: Could not close session!
inep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): Resource temporarily unavailable
outep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): Resource temporarily unavailable
OK.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the final solution I figured out that worked:**

Since nothing was correctly working, I'm not sure what was installed that conflicted with my MTP device not being recognized.

I've load a picture of the option I used from my Lubuntu 15.10 installation USB flash drive to fix the issue:
[image: Reinstall Lubuntu 15.10 Documents, Music, and Other Personal Files Will Be Kept. Option]

This option fixed the problem and all I had to do was reinstall what I didn't have working after the re-install of the OS which took a short amount of time. Most my apps where working without issue and desktop was as it was before untouched. I just uploaded this picture from my phone using Lubuntu without any options or tricks for this post! Thank you for those that helped me out with suggestions!

PROBLEM RESOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue was came to me on ubuntu 15.10.I solved it by enabling usb debuging.Go to Settings>Developer Options> and enable USB Debugging.If that doesnot work try by restarting both of your  devices.

Comment: Tried both suggestions and nothing has changed. Anyone else wish have something more direct. I can't get MTP to load anymore no matter the method used.